# How to use webclient and DownloadStringCompleted windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone

I have class GetInfo (get object from server), Page1.xaml, Page2.xaml. I want tranmission object value from Page1 to Page2 
This is my code

**Class GetInfo**

```
  Class GetInfo{   
    Info use_info; //(Info is class)
    public GetInfo(Info user_info)
    {
        this.user_info = user_info;
    }

    public void UseWebClient()
    {

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
                getInfo(e.Result);
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/user_info.php?id=1"));
    }
    void getInfo()
    {
        I will Parse JSon string get from server become Info object...
    }
```

}

**Class Page1.cs**//

```
Info user_info;
GetInfo userInfo;
public Page1()//constructor
{
   userInfo = new GetInfo(user_info);
}
private void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   userInfo.UseWebClient();

   //THIS IS PROBLEM
   if(user_info.name != null) //name is public properties;
   {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["user_info"] = user_info;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Check Connect!", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK)
      if(result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
         Application.Current.Terminate();  
   }
}
```

I know DownloadStringCompleted call when event LayoutRoot_Loaded() finish. Problem is I can't move to Page2 if LayoutRoot_Loaded() not finish.
I need solution to solve the problem
Thanks!

Comment: Then why don't you move the call to `NavigationService.Navigate` in the `DownloadStringCompleted` event of your webclient?

Comment: I've tried but error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)'"